# Can you get multiple "Notable Question" badges for the same question?

Tags: support, badges, views

I was wondering if you could get a "Notable Question" badge for the same question twice? For example, if I have 2.5K views on a question, then I get another 2.5K views for it, will I get two "Notable Question" badges?

Comment: There's a higher tier after that one; Famous, for 10k views.  Thing would get awful cluttered if you got four Notables and one Famous, all for the same metric, I'd think.

Comment: The [FAQ on badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/398063) (possible dupe?) Isn't completely clear, but no. And you know what-if maybe we should make that clearer in said FAQ

Comment: This wasn't clear in the full list of badge criteria, either, so I'm leaving this open. I'm going to edit it to make it clear, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no badge which you can earn multiple times for a single post, and [Notable Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/27/notable-question) is no exception to this. It does have a higher tier gold equivalent: [Famous Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/28/famous-question) for 10,000 views.

Note that if these badges *would* stack somehow, you would already have earned two [Popular Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/26/popular-question) badges for getting 2,000 views.